# Defining class functions inside class functions: Python

Tags: python, class, nested

I have a code in which I want to defina a class function inside a class function. Here's a simpler example of what I want to do. The goal of this program is to print 4.

```
>>> class bluh:
...     def haha(self):
...             print 3
...     def __init__(self):
...             def haha(self):
...                     print 4
... 
>>> x = bluh()
>>> x.haha()
3
```

How should I actually write this program to do what I want?

Comment: If your goal is to print 4, why are you doing this instead of just defining `haha` as a regular method?  What are you hoping to gain by doing it this way?

Comment: My goal isn't *actually* to print 4. This is just much simpler version of what I'm trying to do, which involves control statements, lots of other methods, etc. I almost put a part explaining this at the end of my post, but eventually decided that most people who frequented this site could figure that out.

Comment: The point is, you haven't explained why you feel it's necessary to use nested functions in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This really depends on what you want to do.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def haha(self):
...         print 3
...     def __init__(self):
...         def haha():
...             print 4
...         self.haha = haha
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.haha
<function haha at 0x7f4539e25aa0>
>>> a.haha()
4
```

In the previous example, `haha` isn't actually a method -- It's just a function.  But it will pick up a reference to `self` from the closure and a lot of the time, that's probably good enough.  If you actually want to monkeypatch/duck punch a new method on an instance, you'll need to use `types.MethodType`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/748858) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This will add a method to a class from an instance.
In most cases not the thing you want to do, but the language makes it just that simple.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def foo(self):
            print "bar"
        self.__class__.foo = foo
```

The use of such a trick can be justified when you build some kind of data-driven self-modifying code (not a every day case for most of us)

Comment: Every time anyone does anything like that, Guido kills a kitten, thus have I heard.

Comment: It depends what you're going to accomplish. One shouldn't do this on a regular basis, but I can see some good use for such a technique.