# Function that has access to self, inside a class method

Tags: python, class, oop, class-method

How to define a function, inside a class method (for example for a `threading` Thread target function), that needs access to `self`?
Is the solution 1. correct or should we use 2.?

1. ```
   import threading, time
   class Foo:
       def __init__(self):
           def f():
               while True:
                   print(self.a)                
                   self.a += 1
                   time.sleep(1)
           self.a = 1
           threading.Thread(target=f).start()
           self.a = 2
   Foo()
   ```

   It seems to work even if `self` is not a parameter of `f`, but is this reliable?
2. ```
   import threading, time
   class Foo:
       def __init__(self):
           self.a = 1
           threading.Thread(target=self.f).start()
           self.a = 2
       def f(self):
           while True:
               print(self.a)                
               self.a += 1
               time.sleep(1)
   Foo()
   ```

This is linked to [Defining class functions inside class functions: Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924987/defining-class-functions-inside-class-functions-python) but not 100% covered by this question.

Comment: #2 might be considered more readable and maintainable, I'd just go with `def _f` to tell outside code it (probably) should not be called directly (as per the convention)

Comment: #1 works because it's a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python)

Comment: @DeepSpace In such contexts, are 1. and 2. the only patterns we see, or is there a (very common) third method that I haven't seen? Maybe   `def __init__(self):`  and inside: `def f(self):`. Is the latter possible inside `__init__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is fine; `f` is redefined every time you call `__init__`, but as it is local to `__init__`, it has access to the entire local scope of `__init__`, including the name `self`.

Whether `__init__` should be starting a new thread is another matter.

Comment: About your last paragraph, yes in my real code, the thread is not started during `__init__`, here it is just for the purpose of the MCVE code.

Answer (score 1):

Either way is reliable its mostly preference, nesting the f function within `__init__` will allow it to have access to (thank you @DeepSpace) variables defined within `__init__`, putting it outside but passing self to it allows for the same thing. I don't believe there is a set "right" way to do this.

Comment: Small nitpicking, but not "inherit" variables, just have access them